# LG G2 vs980 not recognized by ADB devices command (Win7 on virtualbox)

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, virtualbox, android-virtual-device

I have been developing android mobile apps via eclipse in school for some time now, deploying the apps to virtual devices. However, I now want to deploy them to my LG G2 android device for testing and speed purposes. I know there are posts about other devices not working, but the solutions are to no avail for me.

I am on virtualbox running windows 7. I have the necessary vb extensions installed and vb DOES detect my LG G2 (asks to view folders..etc), however eclipse/adb on my vb cannot find it still.

I have put what I thought is the proper device vendor id (1004, 0232) in the adb_usb.ini file since some others found that to help get their device detected.

I have done the commands adb kill-server & start-server many times. I have restarted the phone and vb also. I have also tried all of the phones connection types (internet/ethernet, MTP)

Some help would be awesome,
Thanks fellas

Comment: Just to check : have you enabled USB debugging on the device?

Comment: Yes, I have. My phone has everything set properly as far as my research has gone.

Comment: @karns was there ever a resolution to this?

Comment: @DanielSmith there was not

Answer (score 47, accepted):

When you plug the phone in, you are given options for the "USB connection method".

**You must select `Internet connection` or `Send Images (PTP)` from the list in order to use USB Debugging tools.**

For selecting `Internet Connection`, the other options sometimes include `Charge phone`, `Media sync`, and `Camera`.

For selecting `Send Images (PTP)`, the other options sometimes include `Charge Phone` and `Media Device (MTP)`.

Comment: Only other thing I had to do was download the USB installer exe from the LG support site for my phone which was a LG VS980

Comment: For my phone, `Internet Connection` was not an option, but `Send Images (PTP)` worked

Comment: For my LG G Pro 2 I have to select 5th option "Send images (PTP)"

Comment: With LG G2 running Android 5.0.2 I had to do what Goodyear posted, neither of the other two options worked. I tried tethering from one of the answers but then that disabled my WiFi and the phone showed up as ????'s and I was unable to start the app from Android Studio.

Comment: You are awesome!!! It worked like a charm! I have been working on it almost 8 hrs. Thanks Daniel.

Answer (score 9):

Here are may be several solutions:

1) When your device connected open `Device manager`(default windows tool) and found `Unknown device` or some not properly recognized device and try to setup driver manually.

2) Enable `USB debugging` option in phone settings:
  go to `Setting->About Phone` and tap several times on `Build Number`,
 then go back (`Settings->Developer -> Options`) and turn it on

3) Try to update your `USB driver/adb` via `Android Manager` launched  from `Eclipse`.

Comment: Pepelac, I get confused whether to do step 1 on my host (also win7) or on my virtualbox. To my understanding, if it can view the files on the phone or give me those options when it connects, arent the drivers all installed properly? I did step 2 already.  I will look into step 3 today

Comment: are you sure that you enable debugging mode in settings, if you can browse folders you are not in debug mode, as I remember.

Comment: If I click "internet" > "Ethernet" for my phone connection type it will go into debug mode, or so it says. But still no results. I have crashed my whole environment so I need to make a new virtual and fresh installs to continue on.

Answer (score 6):

When I upgraded my LG g2 from Android 4.4 to 5.0.2, usb debugging stopped working.

I didnt have an "Internet" option for USB connection method.

Through lots of trial, error, searching, experimenting, the I found that enabling "USB tethering" (in Settings -> Tethering & Networks -> USB Tethering) did the trick.  Once I enabled USB tethering, I could download debugging programs via adb/AndroidStudio.  Before USB tethering enabled, adb could not recognize my 5.0.2 device.

Comment: I should add that I am using a Linux box, not a Windows machine.

Comment: I am on a Windows 8 box, and enabling tethering allow me to connect through MTP or charge only.

Answer (score 0):

How to Setup ADB on Windows

```
Download the Android SDK package for Windows [android-sdk_r21.1-windows.zip]
Extract the zip files to your C:\ drive. Now you have a folder android-sdk-linux
Double click on SDK Manager to initiate the SDK manager. You shall perceive the following window.
Make sure everything is un-ticked. Now select Android SDK Platform-tools and install it.
During the next window, you will be prompted. Accept the license and click on Install.
When the installation is complete, close the window.
The SDK manager has now download the platform-tools successfully, which certainly includes our prior ADB.
The next step is to define the path where ADB is present.
Go to C:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools and take note of this path.
Go to desktop, right click on Computer and select Properties.
On the left pane, click on Advanced System Settings and a new window shall open.
Select Environment Variables under Advanced tab.
Select Path variable and click edit.
Now add the path we noted in step #9 to the variable value and hit OK.
Confirm and apply all the changes.
To confirm that ADB has been configured properly, open CMD window and type in:

adb

You now have ADB successfully installed and configured on your Windows machine
```