# Eclipse IDE won't recognize LG G2 (android 4.4.2 kitkat)

Tags: android, mobile

i enabled the developer option and the USB debugging mode on LG G2 (android 4.4.2).
i cant manage to get it recognize by Eclipse IDE , how can i do that? do i need any other software ?

Comment: try first to restart eclipse

Comment: Are you on windows or Mac or Linux?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22237357/lg-g2-vs980-not-recognized-by-adb-devices-command-win7-on-virtualbox

Comment: Check that the drivers are installed correctly. If the OS does not recognize the device, neither would eclipse. If you are on Windows, check in the Device Manager.

Answer (score 1):

First check if you can find it through `adb` on the command line

```
adb devices
```

if you can't it might be one of these reasons:

- Have you installed the drivers?
- I've noticed in my phone that it can't be used to debug when it is in the "Media Device" mode in Settings -> Storage -> USB Computer Connection

Answer (score 0):

test if adb recognize your phone?

in cmd.exe type :

```
adb devices
```

if result is look like :

> List of devices attached

You should install you phone USB driver.

Comment: make sure you added platfor-tools path in your environment variables